# different answers between Google's site and Google's API

Tags: java, android, google-api

I'm trying to write JAVA code to get answers from google.
The code that I write work just fine with English only, but when I try to add some Hebrew characters, the answers that I get are different from when I write it on Google's website.
Here is the code:

```
String address = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=";
String charset = "UTF-8";
URL url;

try 
{
    url = new URL(address + URLEncoder.encode(artistAndSong + site, charset));
          //The url seems right, and it's the same as the url that appear on the web
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), charset);
    GoogleResults results = new Gson().fromJson(reader, GoogleResults.class);
    res =(results.getResponseData().getResults().get(0).getUrl());
          //This is the part where I see that the answers are not the same
}

class GoogleResults{

private ResponseData responseData;
public ResponseData getResponseData() { return responseData; }
public void setResponseData(ResponseData responseData) { this.responseData = responseData; }
public String toString() { return "ResponseData[" + responseData + "]"; }

static class ResponseData {
    private List<Result> results;
    public List<Result> getResults() { return results; }
    public void setResults(List<Result> results) { this.results = results; }
    public String toString() { return "Results[" + results + "]"; }
}

static class Result {
    private String url;
    private String title;
    public String getUrl() { return url; }
    public String getTitle() { return title; }
    public void setUrl(String url) { this.url = url; }
    public void setTitle(String title) { this.title = title; }
    public String toString() { return "Result[url:" + url +",title:" + title + "]"; }
}
}
```

Does anybody have an Idea? I trying to solve that for a couple a days already... (Also, I tried to play with the unicode, but it didn't seems to solve it..)
Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Google answers are personalized based on your previous searches. Try searching for the same thing when logged in with your account, and when you're not logged in (try incognito window if you're using Chrome for example) and the results should vary.

I think that's what is happening to you.

No obvious flaws in your code, whatsoever.

Comment: Yes, I thought about it, but I still got the same result... :(

Answer (score 0):

You may encounter one or more of these conditions :

- As @darijan said : when you're logged in or not
- Cookies already present or not
- Maybe some sort of UserAgent discrimination
- As Google is rolling out progressively upgrades of their algorithm, we can imagine that the Search API does not use the exact same version as website's one.

Answer (score 0):

Google Api is fetching results very different from those retrieved with Google Website. This is commonly known in "SEO world". This is very sad, because this is the main reason for people working on SEO to write their own crawlers. These programs are making queries to Google Website instead of Google Api. Have you ever seen `captcha` on Google Search site? Have you ever been blocked by Google Search site with message like "We have detected an automated traffic from your network. Please contact your Internet Service Provider."?
If Google would fetch the same results on website and on api, then SEO companies would stop to trick their website to get the correct results.

So the answer is `There is no bug in your code - this is Google's fault.`